# How can I use the type from TypeScript for flowtype in React Native

Tags: typescript-typings, flowtype

I use VSCode IDE to develop React Native apps. I found that the IDE provides type info from TypeScript, but I can't use it directly with [flowtype](https://flow.org/).

For example

```js
render = () => (
  <WebView
    onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
  />
)

onNavigationStateChange = (navState: NavState) => {
  //...
};
```

The type `NavState` could be found in the `index.d.ts` provided by VSCode, but it can't be used in the flow.js.

Can I use types from TypeScript files in my React Native project?

If not, how can I know the correct types in React Native?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. You could transform the .d.ts files into .flow.js files. Although TypeScript looks pretty much like Flow, it doesn't support the same features. So I don't think that Flow will ever support .d.ts files completely. Maybe they'll support parts of them in the future. Here is the Github [issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7) to this topic.